# tensorflow stuck at sess.run()

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I am running code from [this github repository: Pointnet](https://github.com/charlesq34/pointnet) for `part_segmentation` with my own data in a similar format but of the size (4096,3) instead of (2048,3).

While training, the code gets stuck at `tf.sess()` while evaluating `train_op` in `train_one_epoch()`. I tried running the code multiple times and some times it gets stuck at first iteration and sometimes on 5th or 6th iteration. 
I have checked that the `feed_dict` is not empty.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: The code worked fine on my laptop (i5,  8GB RAM, 1 GB Nvidia Geforce GT 525M) when I ran the exact same code. Any help with why this occurred is appreciated.